# In Python, how to access values for first name and last name plus full name when using jinja in html?

Tags: python, html, jinja2

Here's what I currently have:

The values for first_name and last_name are showing as the output but not the full name.

````
            {% for user in users %}
            <tr>
                <td> {{user['first_name']}} </td>
                <td> {{user['last_name']}} </td>
                <td> {{user['first_name'],['last_name']}} </td>
            {% endfor %}
                
            </tr>```
````

Comment: Did you mean `{{user['first_name']}} {{user['last_name']}}`?

Comment: YES! Thank you!!! :)